# Why does this not return 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like:

```
select nvl(nvl(sum(a.quantity),0)-nvl(cc.quantityCor,0),0) 
    from RCV_TRANSACTIONS a 
        LEFT JOIN (select c.shipment_line_id,c.oe_order_line_id,nvl(sum(c.quantity),0) quantityCor 
                   from RCV_TRANSACTIONS c
                   where c.TRANSACTION_TYPE='CORRECT' 
                   group by c.shipment_line_id,c.oe_order_line_id) cc on (a.shipment_line_id=cc.shipment_line_id and a.shipment_line_id=7085740)
    where a.transaction_type='DELIVER'
        and a.shipment_line_id=7085740
    group by nvl(cc.quantityCor,0);
```

The query runs OK, but returns no value.  I want it to return 0 if there is no quantity found.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are grouping by quantityCor so as to get one result row per quantityCor, but in case there are no rows matching your criteria in the table, you want to return one result row with the value 0?

Comment: Are you sure that these conditions: `a.transaction_type='DELIVER' and a.shipment_line_id=7085740` return any rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregation query with a `GROUP BY` returns no rows if all rows are filtered out.

An aggregation query with *no* `GROUP BY` always returns one row, even if all rows are filtered out.

So, just remove the `GROUP BY`.  And change the `SELECT` to:

```
select coalesce(sum(a.quantity), 0) - coalesce(max(cc.quantityCor), 0)
```

Comment: As per usual, spot on Gordon.  Thanks buddy.

Comment: I would upvote this again if I could.  Just reread due to a similar issue.  I will post another example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but it seems you merely want to subtract CORRECT quantity from DELIVER quantity for shipment 7085740. You don't need a complicated query for that. Especially your `GROUP BY` clauses make no sense if that is what you are after.

One way to write this query would be:

```
select 
  sum(case when transaction_type = 'DELIVER' then quantity else 0 end) -
  sum(case when transaction_type = 'CORRECT' then quantity else 0 end) as diff
from rcv_transactions
where shipment_line_id = 7085740;
```

Comment: Certainly reads better.  I might use this instead, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a query like this and was trying to return 'X' when the item is not valid.

```
SELECT case when segment1 is not null then segment1 else 'X' end
--INTO v_orgValidItem
FROM mtl_system_items_b
WHERE segment1='1676001000'--'Jul-00'--l_item
     and organization_id=168;
```

..but it was returning NULL.

Changed to use aggregation with no group by and now it returns 'X' when the item is not valid.

```
SELECT case when max(segment1) is not null then max(segment1) else 'X' end valid
--INTO v_orgValidItem
FROM mtl_system_items_b
WHERE segment1='1676001000'--'Jul-00'--l_item
    and organization_id=168;--l_ship_to_organization_id_pb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, proving the order of operations really matters.

When there is no match for this quote number, this query returns NULL:

```
SELECT MAX(NVL(QUOTE_VENDOR_QUOTE_NUMBER,0)) 
    FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL 
    WHERE QUOTE_VENDOR_QUOTE_NUMBER='foo.bar';
```

..reversing the order of MAX and NVL makes all the difference.  This query returns the NULL value condition:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(QUOTE_VENDOR_QUOTE_NUMBER),0) 
    FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL 
    WHERE QUOTE_VENDOR_QUOTE_NUMBER='foo.bar';
```